# Copy s3 "directory" to local directory

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 "directory" (yes I know it's an object store and the directory is actually just a prefix) that I want to copy to a local directory.

I want a code snippet that does this in Scala.

(Existing questions use the CLI, or copy bucket-to-bucket)

Answer (score 1):

Scala is interoperable with Java, so you could use the AWS Java SDK.

Please note that there is no API call to copy a directory. You would need to obtain a listing, then iterate through the list and copy each object individually.

See: [Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingJava.html)

Comment: Thank you for trying to be helpful. I was already aware of all of that, which is why I asked for a code snippet instead of help. It seems really bizarre to me that there isn't already one floating around. If you want to provide a code snippet I'll accept your answer, otherwise I'll provide that snippet myself and accept that answer.